# using YUI.all checking for classes and adding classes

Tags: javascript, html, yui3

in jQuery I would do it differently but I am editing YUI code and am trying not to mix and match.

I have an HTML item like this:

```
<div class="market">
    <button class="area1 region03 optionSelected" data-type="market" data-vendor="1">Tulsa</button>
    <button class="area1 region03" data-type="market" data-vendor="1">Houston</button>
    <button class="area1 region03" data-type="market" data-vendor="1">Kansas City</button>
</div>
<div class="region">
    <button class="area1 region03" data-type="region" data-vendor="1">Midwest</button>
</div>
```

The possible options are that it has a class of optionSelected or preOptionSelected.  If I click on it directly it is optionSelected and I don't want anything else to bother it.  But if I click on another button it needs to test if it (and all other buttons in the same data-type) have optionSelected in the class.

Right now I'm using the following to apply preOptionSelected to all buttons in the data-type:

```
VZW.all('.region03').addClass('preOptionSelected');
```

This adds the class preOptionSelected but I want it to test for optionSelected first.  I'm also migrating to data- for each region and area - how do I test for those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My edits got eaten. You could possibly simplify your check to

```
if (subNode.getData('region') === node.getData('region') 
        && !subNode.hasClass('selectorButton')) {
    subNode.addClass('preOptionSelect');
}
```

but what you have there is reasonably idiomatic YUI3, so if it works, go with it!

Comment: yeah - I need it to cycle through a mess of buttons (some tabs will hold more than 30) sorted into 'market', 'region', and 'area'.  Each triggering a group based on region or area.  Its a mess and I couldn't figure out how the guy was doing it before me so I decided to go old school.  Eventually I'll migrate it to pure jQuery as a better option than YUI3.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, if you have more YUI3 questions before you migrate, try the #yui IRC channel at freenode.net -- the folks there are pretty helpful. Also see http://jsrosettastone.com, which maps common jQuery and YUI3 calls to each other.

Comment: I've decided to wipe out the YUI3 in favor of jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, since I'm learning YUI3 (legacy code) it took me a bit to figure it out:

```
VZW.all('.market button').each(function(subNode){
    if (subNode.getData('region') == node.getData('region')) {
        if (subNode.hasClass('selectorButton') {
            return false;
        } else {
            subNode.addClass('preOptionSelect');
        }
    }
});
```

if there's a better way I'm happy to hear it but this will all get moved to jQuery in the next few months so working works.

Comment: You could simplify to something like:

Comment: Sorry, I started typing, then hit return on accident, then realized my response would display better as full-fledged answer. :) See above.